# MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect unavailable in monotouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, mapkit

I am converting an example from Objective-C to c# and it used MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect. I am not able to find the equivilent in MonoTouch. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pinvoke for this function is (presently) missing from MonoTouch. Based on the documentation [1] the right pinvoke should look like:

```
[DllImport (Constants.MapKitLibrary, EntryPoint="MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect")]
extern static public MKCoordinateRegion FromMapRect (MKMapRect rect);
```

Add this into your code (inside a type and with the right 'using' namespaces) and it *should* work fine :-)

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html

**UPDATE:** Newer MonoTouch releases have this new method (MonoTouch 4.2.x+)